# Can you dynamically expand multiple times in a DAG using Airflow 2.30

Tags: python, dynamic, mapping, airflow, etl

As of Airflow 2.3, the .expand() and .partial() syntax were introduced to allow for dynamically creating task instances for a list or a map.

Is it possible to expand multiple times? Ie:
Task 1 -> [1,2,3,4,5]
Task 2 expands on task 1 and creates list of lists [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mecj1.png), [2,2], [3,3,3] etc. respectively.
Task 3 expands *again* to print out separately so 15 tasks.

Currently it seems that the input from task 2 gets the 5 values versus expanding a second time.

```
    @task
    def extract():
        return ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    @task
    def transform(value: str) -> typing.List[str]:
        return [value] * int(value)

    @task
    def load(value: str):
        print(value)

    order_data = extract()
    results = transform.expand(value=order_data)
    load.expand(value=results)
```

Is this possible or would I have to create the tasks in another way?

[Graph Diagram of Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mecj1.png)